# How do I access React State properties using TypeScript? Get property does not exist on type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have defined a type, I get the expected data from my API. However, when I try access a property I get error `Property 'deployed' does not exist on type 'Service[]'.`. I'm confused because deployed is a property?

Here is my type:

```
export interface Service {
    service: String,
    deployed: String,
    message: String[]
}
```

Here is API request:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { apiBaseURL } from '../constants';
import { Service } from '../types'

export const getStatus = async () => {
    const { data: status } = await axios.get<Service[]>(`${apiBaseURL}/status`);
    return status;
}
```

Code with error:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { getStatus } from './services/status';
import { Service } from './types';

function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState<Service[]>([]);
  
  React.useEffect(()  => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await getStatus();
      setStatus(response);
      console.log(status);
    })()
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <h1>App</h1>
      </header>
      {status && (
        <p>{status.deployed}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```js
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState<Service[]>([]);
```

Says, `status` is a an **array** of `Service`.

This line:

```tsx
        <p>{status.deployed}</p>
```

Says, you want access `deployed` method of that array. Which is wrong.

A possible way to check whether this hypothesis is right, would be to try to access `deployed` on an element of that array.

For example, assuming you have validated that there exists at least one element in `status` array, this:

```tsx
        <p>{status[0].deployed}</p>
```

or if you wanted to print all the deployed status, something like this:

```
        {!!status && status.map(s => <p key={s.service}>{s.deployed}</p>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Service[]` is an array. The array type does not have a property called `deployed`